# Powershell Multi-choice Menu and Sub menu

Tags: powershell, menu, submenu

I coming from a vb script back ground in to the world of powershell
currently i am in the process of developing a console application with
a main menu and multiple-sub main menus.

i would like the menu system to work like a cascade effect for example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                     Main Menu 
clear
write-host "A"
write-host "B"
write-host "C"
write-host "D"

#When the user choose a letter the use would then 
#forwarded to the letter A menu

$Choice = read-host ''"Please enter your Choice"

--------------------------------------------------------
                     Menu A
#If the user selects any of the options available from (A-Test1 to A-Test3) in #Menu A for example A-Test1:
#The menu A-Test1 will show up and  display a menu of a list of
#actions to perform or return the user back to the menu A.

write-host "A-Test1"
write-host "A-Test2"
write-host "A-Test3"
write-host "A-Test4"
write-host "Exit " # Exit will return the user back to the main menu
                   # To select another choice.
$select = read-host ''"Please select from menu A:"
```

Comment: You might have better luck getting help if you show what you've tried, and what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you could create a menu system. Personally, I have used this format in the past for a menu driven, TUI script:

```
function mainMenu {
    $mainMenu = 'X'
    while($mainMenu -ne ''){
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "`n`t`t My Script`n"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Main Menu"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "`n["; Write-Host -NoNewline "1"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "]"; `
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan " Submenu1"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "`n["; Write-Host -NoNewline "2"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "]"; `
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan " Submenu2"
        $mainMenu = Read-Host "`nSelection (leave blank to quit)"
        # Launch submenu1
        if($mainMenu -eq 1){
            subMenu1
        }
        # Launch submenu2
        if($mainMenu -eq 2){
            subMenu2
        }
    }
}

function subMenu1 {
    $subMenu1 = 'X'
    while($subMenu1 -ne ''){
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "`n`t`t My Script`n"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Sub Menu 1"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "`n["; Write-Host -NoNewline "1"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "]"; `
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan " Say hello"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "`n["; Write-Host -NoNewline "2"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "]"; `
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan " Say goodbye"
        $subMenu1 = Read-Host "`nSelection (leave blank to quit)"
        $timeStamp = Get-Date -Uformat %m%d%y%H%M
        # Option 1
        if($subMenu1 -eq 1){
            Write-Host 'Hello!'
            # Pause and wait for input before going back to the menu
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "`nScript execution complete."
            Write-Host "`nPress any key to return to the previous menu"
            [void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
        }
        # Option 2
        if($subMenu1 -eq 2){
            Write-Host 'Goodbye!'
            # Pause and wait for input before going back to the menu
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "`nScript execution complete."
            Write-Host "`nPress any key to return to the previous menu"
            [void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
        }
    }
}

function subMenu2 {
    $subMenu2 = 'X'
    while($subMenu2 -ne ''){
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "`n`t`t My Script`n"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Sub Menu 2"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "`n["; Write-Host -NoNewline "1"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "]"; `
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan " Show processes"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "`n["; Write-Host -NoNewline "2"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline "]"; `
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan " Show PS Version"
        $subMenu2 = Read-Host "`nSelection (leave blank to quit)"
        $timeStamp = Get-Date -Uformat %m%d%y%H%M
        # Option 1
        if($subMenu2 -eq 1){
            Get-Process
            # Pause and wait for input before going back to the menu
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "`nScript execution complete."
            Write-Host "`nPress any key to return to the previous menu"
            [void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
        }
        # Option 2
        if($subMenu2 -eq 2){
            $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
            # Pause and wait for input before going back to the menu
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "`nScript execution complete."
            Write-Host "`nPress any key to return to the previous menu"
            [void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
        }
    }
}

mainMenu
```

You can nest as many menus deep as you need or put your code to execute at any level. I have since switched to using WinForms when I need a user-friendly tool, but this format has served me well for a while (and I still use it for some scripts in my lab where I don't feel like creating a full GUI).

The only part that might be confusing is the pause I have in there after your code executes waiting for a user to press any key. If you don't have that in there, the script will clear the console and go back to the menu after your code executes. I put that in so that I can review the output before returning to the menu system.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try that. here is an example of my code