# Sub-Menu within Menu

Tags: powershell, menu

I would like to show a new menu within a menu to giver users different options. Here is what I have but I cannot get the sub menu to work.

```
function Show-MainMenu
    {
        param (
            [string]$Title = 'IT Test'
        )
        Clear-Host
        Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
        Write-Host "Select Type of Test:"
        Write-Host "`n"
        Write-Host "1: Server Mode"
        Write-Host "2: Client Mode"
        Write-Host "`n"
        Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
        Write-Host "`n"
    }
    
    function ServerMode
    {
        Write-Host "Server Mode"
    }
    function ClientMode
    {
        Write-Host "Client Mode"
    }
    
    
    do
    {
        Show-MainMenu –Title 'IT Test'
        $input = Read-Host "Enter your Selection"
        switch ($input)
        {
            '1' {               
                    ServerMode
                } 
            '2' {
                    ClientMode
                }
    
            'q' {
                     return
                }
        }
        pause
    }
    until ($input -eq 'q')
```

I would like:

```
MainMenu

    A. Server Mode

    B. Client Mode

(If A is selected)

MainMenu2

    A. ServerA

    B. ServerB
```

Comment: This is a very common thing, with tons of examples all over the web. What did you search for before going down this pat?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. This is just one way.

You could create functions for each menu going through a switch so that you could
keep calling new menus

```
function mainMenu()
{
    clear
    switch(Read-Host "1 Delete
2 Create
3 Modify
4 Remove
X Exit"){
        X {break}
        2 {createMenu}
        default {"N/A"}
    }
}

function createMenu()
{
    clear
    switch(Read-Host "Please select an option `
1 Delete a file
2 Delete a folder
3 Delete another file
4 Delete another folder
5 Back to main menu"){
        5 {mainMenu}
        default {"N/A"}
    }
}

mainMenu
```

or even this example posted in the past here on SO:

[Powershell Multi-choice Menu and Sub menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924659/powershell-multi-choice-menu-and-sub-menu)

Which could make your query a duplicate question, relative to your goals.

You also did not have to start this from scratch. There are modules in the MS powershellgallery.com for such use cases, that you can use as-is or tweak as needed.

```
Find-Module -Name '*menu*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Version  Name                     Repository Description                                                                                     
-------  ----                     ---------- -----------                                                                                     
1.0.7    ps-menu                  PSGallery  Powershell module to generate interactive console menu                                          
2.21     DosInstallUtilities.Menu PSGallery  Functions to create menus                                                                       
1.0.1    PSScriptMenuGui          PSGallery  Use a CSV file to make a graphical menu of PowerShell scripts. Easy to customise and fast to ...
1.0.2003 SS.CliMenu               PSGallery  CLI menu infrastructure for PowerShell. ...                                                     
1.0.0.0  SimpleMenu               PSGallery  Create and invoke a simple menu interface.                                                      
0.3      InteractiveMenu          PSGallery  Powershell interactive menu                                                                     
1.0.52.0 CliMenu                  PSGallery  Easily build and edit CLI menus in Powershell                                                   
0.2      MenuShell                PSGallery  Make console menus in seconds with MenuShell                                                    
0.1.1    ServerOpsMenu            PSGallery  PowerShell module to provide maintenance menu for Windows servers                               
1.0.0.2  MenuSelect               PSGallery  Module description                                                                              
0.1.1    PSMenu                   PSGallery  Powershell module to generate interactive console menu....                                      
1.0.4    SLMenu                   PSGallery  Text User Interface Module for Powershell Console                                               
0.5      ContextSensitiveMenus    PSGallery  Allows you to add type-sensitive context menus to WPF controls    
#>
```